# Android: User registration with couchbase

Tags: android, mobile, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I have been using [this](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/installation/android/index.html?language=ios) example as a guide to let users sign up to my application but it's  not working. There are no syntax errors but for some reason my app is not communicating with the server. Below is the SignupActivity.java that I'm using:

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

public static final String DB_NAME = "myapp";

private Database mDatabase = null;

@Bind(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
@Bind(R.id.input_firstname) EditText _firstnameText;
@Bind(R.id.input_lastname) EditText _lastnameText;
@Bind(R.id.input_confirmpassword) EditText _confirmpasswordText;
@Bind(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
@Bind(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
@Bind(R.id.btn_signup) Button _signupButton;
@Bind(R.id.link_login) TextView _loginLink;
@Bind(R.id.ScrollViewSignup)    ScrollView _scrollLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
ButterKnife.bind(this);

_signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyUtilities.hideSoftKey(SignupActivity.this,v);
        signup();
    }
});

_loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
        finish();
    }
});
_scrollLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

// Create a manager
Manager manager = null;
try {
    manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Create or open the database named app
Database database = null;
try {
    database = manager.getDatabase(DB_NAME);
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// The properties that will be saved on the document
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("name", _nameText);
properties.put("password", _passwordText);
properties.put("firstname", _firstnameText);
properties.put("surname", _lastnameText);
properties.put("email", _emailText);


// Create a new document
Document document = database.createDocument();

// Save the document to the database
try {
    document.putProperties(properties);
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Log the document ID (generated by the database)
// and properties
Log.d(DB_NAME, String.format("Document ID :: %s", document.getId()));
Log.d(DB_NAME, String.format("Learning %s with %s %s %s %s", (String) document.getProperty("name"), (String) document.getProperty("password"),(String) document.getProperty("firstname"),
        (String) document.getProperty("surname"), (String) document.getProperty("email") ));

// Create replicators to push & pull changes to & from Sync Gateway.
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://serverurl:8080/REST-Model-context-root/resources/register");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Replication push = database.createPushReplication(url);
push.setContinuous(true);

// Start replicators
push.start();
}

public void signup() {

if (!validate()) {
    onSignupFailed();
    return;
}

_signupButton.setEnabled(false);

final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this,
        R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
progressDialog.show();

String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();


new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
                // depending on success
                onSignupSuccess();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, 3000);
}


public void onSignupSuccess() {
_signupButton.setEnabled(true);
setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
finish();
}

public void onSignupFailed() {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

_signupButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public boolean validate() {
boolean valid = true;

String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
    _nameText.setError("at least 3 characters");
    valid = false;
} else {
    _nameText.setError(null);
}

if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
    _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
    valid = false;
} else {
    _emailText.setError(null);
}

if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
    _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
    valid = false;
} else {
    _passwordText.setError(null);
}

return valid;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

MyUtilities.hideSoftKey(SignupActivity.this,v);
return true;
  }
}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated!!

Comment: Your server URL is local - are you sure the server works as expected. Perhaps there are ways to turn the library debug mode and you can see what is wrong.

Comment: the server works fine, but is not local, why did you think it is local?

Comment: It looks like you're creating a document with username, password, etc., and setting up a push replication.  You're question isn't clear.  Are you saying you don't see the information replicated?  Are you using Sync Gateway?  What do you see in the Sync Gateway log output?

Comment: this is the log output: D/HelloWorld: Database created
D/HelloWorld: docContent={nationality=, password=, dateOfBirth=, lastname=, email=, name=, firstname=, message=Hello Couchbase Lite}